# Error instaling windows Azure workflow in SharePoint2013 Preview

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

[image]

Can someone shine some light on this?

Log Details:

```
Error] [7/19/2012 11:26:38 PM]: System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException: Could not successfully create management Service Bus entity 'WF_Management/WFTOPIC' with multiple retries within timespan of 00:02:05.6367188. ---> System.TimeoutException: Could not successfully create management Service Bus entity 'WF_Management/WFTOPIC' with multiple retries within timespan of 00:02:05.6367188. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. Authorization failed for specified action: Manage..TrackingId:a2118b4a-a375-4e9e-a2f8-6ae7e04052d9,TimeStamp:7/19/2012 11:26:38 AM ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.ServiceBusResourceOperations.CreateOrUpdateAsyncResult`1.EndGetResponse(CreateOrUpdateAsyncResult`1 thisPtr, IAsyncResult ar)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace:


Exception rethrown at [0]:
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.NamespaceManager.CreateOrUpdateTopicAsyncResult.CreateDescription(CreateOrUpdateTopicAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)

Exception rethrown at [1]:
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.Workflow.Management.ManagementEntitiesCreator.CreateManagementEntitiesAsyncResult.EndCreateTopic(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.Workflow.Common.BackoffRetryAsyncResult.IsolateWithRetry(IAsyncResult result)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Workflow.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.Workflow.Administration.ServiceUpdateManager.CreateManagementEntities(IList`1 namespaceManagerUris, ServiceBusClientCredentialType clientCredentialType, IDictionary`2 arguments, TimeSpan retryTimeout)
   at Microsoft.Workflow.Deployment.Commands.WorkflowServiceConfigHelper.SetWFRuntimeSettings(String resourceDBConnectionString, String config)
   at Microsoft.Workflow.Deployment.Commands.AddWFHost.CallWFRuntimeSettings(Service wfserviceInfo)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.Workflow.Deployment.ConfigWizard.CommandletHelper.InvokePowershell(Command command, Action`2 updateProgress)
   at Microsoft.Workflow.Deployment.ConfigWizard.ProgressPageViewModel.AddWFNode(FarmCreationModel model, Boolean isFirstCommand)
```

Comment: I have the very same issue and of course I use fully qualified domain names. I went so far as creating an AD administrators group for both the workflow and service bus. I ensured my firewall is turned off on both servers and I still get this error. Has anyone got this to configure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the runas name didn’t resolve properly and that is why unauthorized exception. If you are in a domain then give fully qualified domain name in the **'runas'** parameter in configuration wizard

For e.g. enter administrator@foodomain.com in the 'runas' field where foodomain is your domain name

Before this clean your machine because of failed installation. For that click on‘Leave Farm’ in the wizard and then delete the databases created. After that click Create default Farm again and enter the runas as above.

Comment: Thanks, specify the user name using the fully qualified domain fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Here are simple steps to install and configure workflow manager:

Install the Microsoft Web Platform Installer 5.0.

Install Workflow Manager .

Apply Cumulative Update 3.0 for Workflow Manager 1.0.

Configure the Workflow Manager.

Install the WorkFlow Manager Client on SharePoint Server.
(Note: Each server in the SharePoint Server farm must have the Workflow Manager Client installed.
When you install Workflow Manager on a server it automatically installs the Workflow Manager Client on that server. You will still need to install the Workflow Manager Client on any additional servers.)

Add Workflow Manager Certificate into SharePoint trust

Register Workflow Proxy for SharePoint Servers.

Verify the Installation.

Greetings,
Peter